# How to prevent Remote Desktop from creating a file named Default.rdp?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I use Remote Desktop on my MacBook to connect to my workplace's Windows server and my own Windows workstation. I have several .rdp files to connect to those machines under different configurations, so I don't really need that Remote Desktop create a Default.rdp file for me. How do I prevent Remote Desktop from creating that file?

Comment: I don't think this would be possible, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score -2):

you can try system properties, find a "remote" tab, uncheck the box that says "allow remote connections", this is at least on Xp, then none will be able to remote control your system, that file is not going to be created either. thanks

Comment: Excuse me if I did not make myself clear: I **do** want to access those Windows computers remotely. What I do **not** want is that the file Remote.rdp be created. Thanks anyway.

Comment: hups, somehow i missed the part with MacBook, from windows at least, if you disable remote control (you can still reach other windows systems) and that file is not going to be created, sorry as I miss red. thanks